# How to back up and restore Oracle 10.2 database programmatically using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automation, oracle10g, database-backups

I am looking for something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_Database.aspx

but for Oracle rather than the SQL Server. I need this for automated testing.

What have I tried? I am not sure where to start. I searched on Google for a potential solution, but did not find anything.

I would appreciate help from the community.

Comment: If you also wish to see this question answered, then please up-vote it so that I could spend more points on a bounty.

Comment: A solution which involves making a call to `SqlPlus.exe` from `C#` with appropriate parameters would also work.